# Still possible to put configuration of entity type in an external class or function, with EF7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 7 and am configuring my entities, within the `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating` override. Back in EF6, each entity's configuration could exist in an external class and then applied using `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add()`. Does something like this exist yet in EF7, or do all model configurations have to be applied within that single `OnModelCreating` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the api you mentioned is not yet present in EF 7...But who actually needs it in the era of extention methods anyway?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(entity => entity.Map());
```

Mapping class:

```
public static class EntityBuilderHelper
{
    public static void Map(this EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> entity)
    {
        entity.ForSqlServerToTable("MyEntityTable");
        entity.Property(e => e.Id)
            .HasColumnName("MyEntityTableId");
    }
}
```